# Class method not working

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
class automat
{
    int stari[50], sf[50], n, nsf, si;

    char m[50][50];

    public:
    automat(int a, int b) { setn(a); setstari(); setnsf(b); intitsf(); initm(); }

    void setn(int a) { n = a; } //init. nr de stari

    void setstari() { for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) stari[i] = i; } // init. starile

    void setnsf(int a) { nsf = a; } // init. nr de stari finale

    void intitsf() { for (int i = 0; i < nsf; i++) sf[i] = 0; } //init stari finale cu 0 la inceput

    void initm() { for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) m[i][j] = NULL; } // init muchii cu 0 la inceput

    void setsf(int a) { sf[a] = 1; } // seteaza o stare finala

    void addm(int a, int b, char c) { m[a][b] = c; } // adauga muchie

    void setsi(int a) { si = a; } // seteaza starea initiala

    void afismuchii()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (m[i][j] != 0)
                    cout << i << " se duce in " << j << " cu " << m[i][j] << endl;
    }
};




int main()
{
    ifstream f("file.txt");

    int n, m, F;
    f >> n; f >> m; f >> F;

    automat a(n, F);

    int x, y; char c;

    f >> x;
    a.setsi(x); //init. stare initiala

    while (F) // init. stari finale
    {
        f >> x;
        a.setsf(x);
        F--;
    }

    while (m) // init. muchii
    {
        f >> x; f >> c; f >> y;
        a.addm(x, y, c);
        m--;
    }

    a.afismuchii();
}
```

Please excuse my commentaries and the name of the functions.

At the end of the program, when i run "  a.afismuchii(); " i should get:

0 goes to 1 with a
0 goes to 1 with b

but instead, the matrix is NULL and i only get:

0 goes to 1 with 
0 goes to 1 with

so the addm() method may not be working properly, but i dont get why.

Comment: Please edit your code, and add proper indentation. Without proper indentation, the code is hard to read. And if it's hard to read, it will be more difficult for someone to help you with your problem.

Comment: We might need to see what's in file.txt. And it's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish. Code is hard enough to read, let alone names/comments in a different language. And to top it off it's formatted extremely poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast (m[i][j]) to static_cast  (m[i][j])

Answer (score 0):

In `automat`, `m` is a 2 dimensional array of type `char`.  The `afismuchii` method is outputting a char of this array to standard output *as a character*, and not as a number, which is what it looks like what you want.  To get a number you need to cast it first.

This is because when you output a `char` to an `ostream` you get the char output, not it's numerical value.  `cout << 'A';` will output an `A`, not `65` which is the numerical value a `char` holding an `A` character usually has .  So the line in `afismuchii` should really be:

```
cout << i << " se duce in " << j << " cu " << static_cast<int>(m[i][j]) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is working because it `cout`s something.
if NULL is defined as 0, it won't `cout` like that.

> but instead, the matrix is NULL and i only get:
>
> 0 goes to 1 with 0 goes to 1 with

Secondly,
Since `m[][]` is `char`, comparing with 0 would not be appropriate.

`if(m[i][j]!=0)`

might have been

`if(m[i][j]!=NULL)`

Lastly,
I advise you to validate the inputs before calling `addm`
as the integers are less than 50 (and not less than 0), and the character is meaningful(readable?).